# Residual plot for residual vs predicted value in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

I have run a KNN model. Now i want to plot the residual vs predicted value plot. Every example from different websites shows that i have to first run a linear regression model. But i couldn't understand how to do this. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.
Here is my model-

```
train, validate, test = np.split(df.sample(frac=1), [int(.6*len(df)), int(.8*len(df))])
x_train = train.iloc[:,[2,5]].values
y_train = train.iloc[:,4].values
x_validate = validate.iloc[:,[2,5]].values
y_validate = validate.iloc[:,4].values
x_test = test.iloc[:,[2,5]].values
y_test = test.iloc[:,4].values
clf=neighbors.KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors = 6)
clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
y_pred = clf.predict(x_validate)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Residuals are nothing but how much your predicted values differ from actual values. So, it's calculated as actual values-predicted values. In your case, it's **residuals = y_test-y_pred**. Now for the plot, just use this;

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.scatter(residuals,y_pred)

plt.show()
```

Comment: normal scattering shows what i wants. Then why using regplot or residplot? Three of these do different things.

Comment: Yes, these three are different. plt.scatter(),as you probably know, gives you a simple way to plot a graph typically between two variables. Just like we plotted graphs in school, it just plots a graph of x and y. Whereas, seaborn.residplot() is a bit more advanced thing, it straightforward plots the residuals by directly taking in predictor/input variable and response/output variable as its parameters, you don't have to calculate residuals by yourself. And seaborn.regplot() plots the best fit regression line along with all the data points, it doesn't plot the residuals like seaborn.residplot()

Comment: you can better understand them here : https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.regplot.html#seaborn.regplot   
https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.residplot.html#seaborn.residplot

Comment: Thank you for making time to answer. It is clear now :)

Comment: Happy coding :D

Answer (score 3):

What is the question? The residuals are simply `y_test-y_pred`. Now use [seaborn's regplot.](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.regplot.html)

Comment: residual = y_pred - y_validate
sns.regplot(x = residual, y = y_pred, data = None, scatter = True, color = 'red')     Is this is ok?

Comment: @nl7 should be fine, how does it look?

Comment: sns.regplot(x = y_pred, y = residual, data = None, scatter = True, color = 'red')    Residuals on y?